# Office.context.ui.messageParent not working in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

For **Chrome 84.0.4147.89** and **Firefox 78.0.2** the `Office.context.ui.messageParent` method no longer works. It still works in Outlook for Mac.

We noticed this problem only a few days ago.

Comment: We are not able to repro it at our end. Can you share the code snippet which you are trying and the error you are seeing.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT There is no error. The code console output suggests a successful call to `messageParent` but the callback supplied to `Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync` does not get called.

Comment: Can you please share the code snippet so that we can try it at our end.